# How much did Korbanos cost to bring?

Tags: money, korban

In the first Perek of Chagiga Beis Hillel says that the minimum for a Shlomim is 2 Mayiah and for an Olah 1 Mayiah. A Mayiah is roughly 0.8 gram of silver which is under a dollar in today's value. I am wondering how much in today's money would it cost to bring a korban.
Additionally how many days a worker would work for a korban?
(When I say Korban I refer to sheep, goat, and cow)

Comment: You might gain some insight studying Korban Oleh, which has a lot written on what the rich should bring vs the poor possibly might find some values in some commentaries as per your question.